# Using Data-Based Database in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio

I created a working Data-Based Database. I can also use this db with the DataGridView.

But how can I create a connection to the database with C#? I searched already before but nothing worked for me.

In my `App.config` is also

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="make_it_server_verwaltung.Properties.Settings.ServerlistConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Serverlist.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

So how can I create a connection to my db and how can I add/delete/change/read my database over C#?

Thank you ^^

[Working DataGridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLqyY.png)

Comment: We'd like to help, but I fear your question is too broad. I'd suggest you try to find some tutorials to follow. And do feel free to come back with more specific questions. A related "this is absolutely not how you write production code" answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712783/how-to-load-data-into-text-box-from-sql-database-table

Comment: You can access your config file with `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["name"];` , I believe